# Setting a limit for stored keys in the node.js in-memory store?

Tags: node.js, in-memory-database, key-value-store

I'm currently writing a simple application that receives a key+value and stores it in the in-memory key-value store (I'm using memdown for node.js).

I would like to set a limit for the number of keys stored (only the last 5 are relevant) but cannot seem to find a code example for that. Would you be able to help?

Thank you!

Comment: Create a wrapper for it which checks if the key values increases the threshold remove the least used 4 keys and remove one to add one more.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this!